# Disable Laravel 5 Auth Bootstrap

Tags: laravel, authentication, web, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel Auth for a website. It seems that Auth is using bootstrap for styling. I would like to disable bootstrap. There is no line that includes bootstrap in my app.blade.php layout so I can't find where is it loaded. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using bootstrap for styling, but name of the css file is app.css.

Go to **resources->views->layouts->app.blade.php** and delete line

```
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```